# Persistent draw color when using \def

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\def\mwe(#1)(#2);{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},rotate={#2}]
        \draw[fill=white] (0,0) circle (1);
        \draw[-latex] (0,0) -- ++(30:1.5);
    \end{scope}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]

    \draw[black!30,fill=blue!15] (0,0) rectangle (6,4);
    %\draw[black]; % simple workaround
    \mwe(5,2)(0);
    \draw[red,-latex] (0,0) -- (2,1);
    \draw[-latex] (1,0) -- (3,1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This produces the output:

[image: output]

As you can see from the output, the arrowhead in the mwe shape, defined with `\def`, inherits the previously used draw color, whereas the circle and the arrow line are still black, like they should be. The subsequent arrowheads also have the correct color, as demonstrated. Therefore, my question for you is but one word: why?

As you can see in the code, I already know a simple workaround for the problem, so this question is more about understanding `tikz` and LaTeX than finding different solutions. Of course, feel free to add a different solution if you want to. (Apart from the `fill=white`, there should be no color definitions in the mwe shape.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick answer: An arrow is more like a path so TikZ does not pass filling-color to it. But in the definition of `Latex`, `Stealth`, `Kite`, `Square`, and `Circle` there is `\pgfusepathqfill` performing some filling. So the *current* <del>filling-color</del>stroke-color is used. You may change the current <del>filling</del> color by a trivial <del>filling-</del>job such as `\fill[yellow];`.

### Long Answer

The first example shows the bug:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[draw=yellow](0,1)--(1,0);
    \draw[-Square](0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

After some tracing I found two macros involved:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[yellow](0,1)--(1,0);
    \def\pgf@arrows@fill@color{green}
    \def\pgf@arrows@stroke@color{blue}
    \draw[-Square](0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

This shows that TikZ allows us to customize the color of arrow tips. Meanwhile it should choose the default color if there is no customization:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[yellow](0,1)--(1,0);
    \def\pgf@arrows@fill@color{}
    \def\pgf@arrows@stroke@color{}
    \draw[-Square](0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

But somehow if I write the code more logically (no `@`), it fails again:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[draw=yellow](0,1)--(1,0);
    \pgfsetfillcolor{green}
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{blue}
    \draw[-Square](0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Turns out that it is the definition of `\pgf@arrows@color@setup` containing something weird:

```
\def\pgf@arrows@color@setup{%
  \ifx\pgf@arrows@stroke@color\pgfutil@empty\else\pgfsetstrokecolor{\pgf@arrows@stroke@color}\fi%
  \ifx\pgf@arrows@fill@color\pgfutil@empty%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx%
    \expandafter\csname\expandafter\string\expandafter\color@pgfstrokecolor\expandafter\endcsname\csname\string\color@pgffillcolor\endcsname%
    \else
      \pgfsetfillcolor{pgfstrokecolor}%????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
    \fi%
  \else%  
    \pgfsetfillcolor{\pgf@arrows@fill@color}%
  \fi%
}
```

I guess the design here is that by default the stroke-color and the fill-color of arrow tips should be the same. But that line will set the fill-color as the current stroke-color (i.e. the color assigned in the pervious line). I commented out this line and the bug disappeared. (At least for our MWEs.)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[red]
    \draw[yellow](0,1)--(1,0);
    \draw[-Square](0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here comes the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[draw=yellow](0,1)--(1,0);
    \draw[-Square](0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[yellow](0,1)--(1,0);
    \def\pgf@arrows@fill@color{green}
    \def\pgf@arrows@stroke@color{blue}
    \draw[-Square](0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[yellow](0,1)--(1,0);
    \def\pgf@arrows@fill@color{}
    \def\pgf@arrows@stroke@color{}
    \draw[-Square](0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[draw=yellow](0,1)--(1,0);
    \pgfsetfillcolor{green}
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{blue}
    \draw[-Square](0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
%\begin{tikzpicture}
%   \draw[draw=yellow](0,1)--(1,0);
%   \pgfsetfillcolor{}
%   \pgfsetstrokecolor{}
%   \draw[-Square](0,0)--(1,1);
%\end{tikzpicture}
\def\pgf@arrows@color@setup{%
  \ifx\pgf@arrows@stroke@color\pgfutil@empty\else\pgfsetstrokecolor{\pgf@arrows@stroke@color}\fi%
  \ifx\pgf@arrows@fill@color\pgfutil@empty%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx%
    \expandafter\csname\expandafter\string\expandafter\color@pgfstrokecolor\expandafter\endcsname\csname\string\color@pgffillcolor\endcsname%
    \else
%      \pgfsetfillcolor{pgfstrokecolor}%
    \fi%
  \else%  
    \pgfsetfillcolor{\pgf@arrows@fill@color}%
  \fi%
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[red]
    \draw[yellow](0,1)--(1,0);
    \draw[-Square](0,0)--(1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\def\mwe(#1)(#2);{
    \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)},rotate={#2}]
        \draw[fill=white](0,0)circle(1);
        \draw[-latex](0,0)--++(30:1.5);
    \end{scope}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
    \draw[black!30,fill=blue!15](0,0)rectangle(6,4);
    \mwe(5,2)(0);
    \draw[red,-latex] (0,0) -- (2,1);
    \draw[-latex] (1,0) -- (3,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,>=latex]
    \draw[->](0,0)--(3,2);
    \draw[draw=green](1.5,1)circle[radius=1];
    \draw[dotted,->](0,2)--(3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The fill color is not the issue here, though. I have updated the example to better illustrate this.

Comment: @eiterorm You are right. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. Although you seem to have found the source of the problem, I'd say the code looks a little neater with the workaround. I assume this bug will be fixed in a future version.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a bug. I can't think of any kind of implementation logic that would justify the arrowhead on the second (dotted) line being green.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick, >=latex]
\draw [->] (0,0) -- (3,2);
\draw [draw=green] (1.5,1) circle [radius=1];
\draw [dotted, ->] (0,2) -- (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The workaround is to explicitly provide the color as a key for every path with an arrow head, either using `draw=black` or just `black`, possibly tying it up in a style.